# Can Visual Studio Express can be used for Commericial purposes?

Tags: visual-studio-express

Can Visual Studio Express be used for commercial purposes if you are not intending to sell the product? Instead I intend to use Visual Studio Express to develop in house tools to boost employee performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [commercial use of Visual Studio Express is allowed.](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs)

> Commercial use of Visual Studio Express
>
> Visual Studio Express products are available at no charge and may be
>   used for commercial, production usage subject to the license terms
>   provided with each product. For example, you can use Express for
>   Windows to create apps that you can then submit for sale in the
>   Windows Store.